# Laying out subviews in a UITableViewCell dynamically

Tags: ios, uitableview, user-interface, swift

This is the most complicated UI related problem I've come across yet. I've been trying to find a solution for literally weeks but no avail. Let em explain.

In this app I'm working on, I need to display a certain list. It's actually a schedule. Here's how it should look like,

[image]

The fields circled by red circles don't change. To explain what change means I have to show you this.

[image]

Its a set of filters which the user can show/hide certain fields and the ones that are circled in the first image are static ones. They can't be toggled on and off.

Now the problem arises with the ones that can be toggled. Here's what it looks like if you turn off the *Show Actions* flag.

[image]

A new label with a blue background replaces the bottom one you can see in the first image.

Here's another one where you disable *Show Time* option and the time labels are gone (yes it affects only for some. Its expected).

[image]

If this filter list were an option list, it would have been easy. Just create a custom cell for each option and you're good to go. But unfortunately the user is able to toggle **multiple** filters! For example the user can turn off both *Show Actions* and *Show Time* and it'd look like the last image but the bottom label would have the blue label in the third image.

To top it all off, the cells' height is dynamic. In iOS 8 creating self resizing cells are easy enough from the IB when you could just add auto layout constraints and done.
But it seems to me that creating these cells from the IB isn't an available option to me. Simply because there are way too many filter combinations a user can make. So the cell's subviews need to adjust to it.

My question is how can I create a dynamic cell like that? My best guess is through code, right? I haven't written my UI in code before so I tried creating a test project to familiarize myself with it. But the problems I'm facing is setting fixed frame sizes makes the dynamic nature obsolete. And how can I move a view to fill up a removed view's space (Last image. Time labels are gone so the name and the id labels move to the left to fill that space).

I know this question is a little too broad. I'm not asking for a straight answer either. I'd really appreciate some pointers, or even a better suggestion on how to approach this because I'm truly at the rock bottom on this issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to give you any precise help since your question is so broad. First, I would recommend watching the 3 videos on Auto Layout from the WWDC 2012 (sessions 202, 228, and 232).

To answer your one example, how to move a view to replace a view that's removed. You would need to make two left edge constraints from the view with the text (Kund Alof...). One with a constant of 0 to the time label with a priority of 1000 (that's the default), and another to the left edge of the cell, also with a constant of 0, but with a lower priority, say 900. As long as the time label is present, the constraint to it will determine the position of the text label, but when it's removed, the lower priority constraint to the left edge will take over and move the label over to the left edge.

Comment: in addition you can change contraints at runtime. e.g. you can write a method `layoutWithFilters:` in the uitableviewcell subclass and change your constraints dynamically.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. Can you please explain about settings those constraints? Here what I did so far. I set a `Vertical Spacing` constraint between the name label and the time label, set its constant to 0 and kept the priority to 1000 ([See](http://i.imgur.com/njc5IPd.png)). Next I created a `Leading Space to Superview` constraint from the name label and set its constant to 0 and priority to 900 ([See](http://i.imgur.com/S3jaNnp.png)). But the result I get it [this](http://i.imgur.com/BrnKMdG.png). Any idea about hat I might be missing?

Comment: @Isuru, that last image is what you get with the time label still present? What constraints do you have on the time label? I also see that red arrow in your scene list -- you should click that and see what errors it's reporting.

Comment: @rdelmar Yes, the time label is there. Its just overlapped by the name label. I added 3 new constraints. `Leading space to superview` and `Top space to superview` to the time label and `Top space to superview` to the name label and now the red warning is gone. But still the result is the same as the last picture I added in my previous comment.

Comment: @Isuru, Is the time label being populated with a value? It sounds like what you have should work as long as the time label is populated (which should give it a width based on the size of the string). You could try adding a width constraint to the time label and see if that helps.

Comment: @Isuru, actually, I thin the priority of 900 is too high. Instead of adding a width constraint to the time label, try setting that lower priority constraint to 700 instead of 900.

Comment: @rdelmar yes, for now I have set the value for the label to _12:00_. I changed the priority level to 700 and now it looks like [this](http://i.imgur.com/vgBwbxB.png). Then I hid the time label but the name label doesn't move to fill the empty space ([See](http://i.imgur.com/G9fXYWN.png)). I uploaded my test project [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t3zslfl77s54zga/Layout.zip?dl=0) if you have time to take a look at it :)

Comment: @Isuru, you can't just hide the time label, you have to remove it from its superview for the new constraint to take over.

Comment: @rdelmar Got it! Thank you. Seems like its possible to achieve what I want but its gonna be a ton of work.